# Gnome overview of windows is small in new Ubuntu 21

Tags: gnome, desktop-background

Hello I have upgraded Ubuntu and now when I press the "Windows" key for window overview, the window previews are smaller than in previous Ubuntu version. Can I make it as big as before, without ugly non-wallpaper frame around it?

I would also like to have wallpaper when I type in gnome search. It used to be there but now wallpaper disappears.

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 21; as the *year* format products are only released on *even* years, and don't come with GNOME as they're server products only. Be aware if you're asking about Ubuntu 21.10 - it's upcoming EOL *warning* notices are already out, eg. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/06/01/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-14-2022/ so it's not a *new* system

Comment: Applies to Ubuntu 22.04 too. I got used to smaller windows, but really do not like screen without wallpaper when searching. Why the good things have to go away?